# Select a column between 4

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with 4 columns named `mobil1, mobile2, tel1, tel2` which in different rows 3 are null or unusable data and only one of them has the right data.

I want to take the one which has data starting with **09** to insert to another table

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (not images.) [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a CASE statement to choose the first correct one:

```
SELECT Other_Columns,
       CASE
          WHEN mobil1 LIKE '09%' THEN mobil1
          WHEN mobile2 LIKE '09%' THEN mobile2
          WHEN tel1 LIKE '09%' THEN tel1
          WHEN tel2 LIKE '09%' THEN tel2
          ELSE NULLL
       END as PhoneNumber
FROM table
```

CASE will parse each option in order to see if the expression evaluates to TRUE.   I have assumed the columns are VARCHAR because the value starts with a 0 which wouldn't show if they were numeric.